# SQL How to update certain row's with data from rows in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm new to SQL and can't seem to get my head around a problem.

I have a table that contains the following columns: product_id, language_id, and description.

What I'm trying to do is copy data from rows where language_id is '2' and paste it to rows where the language_id is '1'.

The following code is something I tried but it produces an error:

```
UPDATE product_description
SET 
    description //incomplete bit
FROM 
(
    SELECT description
    FROM description
    WHERE language_id = 2
)
WHERE product_description.language_id = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `join`:

```
UPDATE product_description pd1 JOIN
       product_description pd2
       ON pd1.product_id = pd2.product_id
    SET pd1.description = pd2.description
    WHERE pd1.language_id = 1 AND
          pd2.language_id = 2;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the answer. I tried to run the code but the error "Unknown column 'pd2.langauge_id' in 'where clause'" pop's up. I'm not sure what's the problem since I'm not sure what pd2 is supposed to be, is it a shortened version od product_description?

Comment: @Gilbert . . . That should be `language_id`.  A typo.

Comment: Yea, I kinda missed that. Everything works fine now, thanks for the help.